# tags <# #> in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I saw these tags in Apple's documentation like in this example from the NSFetchResultsController Class reference :

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = <#Managed object context#>;
```

I guess it is some kind of reference to some #define or constant.

Can somebody explained it to me ?

Thanks

Comment: it's just a generic notation for proper context. For example : `NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the notation for Xcode placeholders. You can paste it into the editor and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to jump and change the placeholder.

Comment: Indeed, the answer meet exactly my question but i had to wait for 10 min to be able to accept it :)